# \rule Margin Spacing Issue for Horizontal Line

Tags: margins, document-classes, cv, resume

How can I get the horizontal line to not enter the right margin.

It doesn't look symmetrical the way I have it.

Ideally I would like the horizontal line to be the same distance from the side of the page on both sides.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\begin{document}

\indent{\textbf{\large{NAME}\\
 {\rule{\paperwidth}{1.5pt}}
 \begin{resume} 
 \vspace{-8mm}

\section{Contact Information}{ Avenue \\  CITY\\ COUNTRY \\  Mobile: +1 (342)     333-3333\\Email: funnyemail@mail.com}

\end{resume} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example does not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\paperwidth` should be replaced by `\resumewidth` and the 'weird' `\vspace{-8mm}` dropped.

**Warning:** res.cls is quite old (2001)!!!

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\begin{document}

\indent{\textbf{\large{NAME}\\
 {\rule{\resumewidth}{1.5pt}}}}%
 \begin{resume} 
% \vspace{-8mm}

\section{Contact Information}{ Avenue \\  CITY\\ COUNTRY \\  Mobile: +1 (342)     333-3333\\Email: funnyemail@mail.com}

\end{resume} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Ideally I would like the horizontal line to be the same distance from the side of the page on both sides."

\textwidth doesn't satisfy the above!

Comment: @Rambi: That's a consequence of the margins of the `res.cls`

Comment: @Chistian: Is there a way to manually enter the width and alignment?  Or is it only possible to use \pagewidth \textwidth etc...

Comment: @Rambi: Use `\resumewidth` instead, but the class is so old, I did not find a documentation and I have no time to dig into this old code right now